# AJAX response to move google map centre

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to make an AJAX request from a rails app using JQueryUJS to retrieve Latitude/Longitude coordinates to which a google map should then re-centre to.

The AJAX response is returning javascript to run, but I am finding that neither trying to manipulate the map object directly or running a function with the javascript code on the client works as neither the variable or function are available.

Why can I not use existing variables? and what alternatives exist to enable re-centering of the map based on an AJAX response?

The code for the attempts to call a function are is as follows:

HTML snippet:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/venues" class="new_venue" data-remote="true" id="new_venue" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
  <div id="entry-form" class="left span8"> 
    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="find_address_button" type="submit" value="Find Address" />
    <div id='map_canvas' class='map_new' data-default-zoom= 16></div>
    <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add Venue" />
  </div> 
</form>
```

Page load JS:

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var default_zoom, latitude, longitude, map, mapOptions, map_centre, moveToLocation;
    moveToLocation = function(lat, lng) {
      var center;
      center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      return map.panTo(center);
    };
    latitude = 52;
    longitude = 0;
    map_centre = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    default_zoom = $("#map_canvas").data("default-zoom");
    mapOptions = {
      center: map_centre,
      zoom: default_zoom,
      scrollwheel: false,
      styles: [
        {
          featureType: "poi",
          elementType: "labels",
          stylers: [
            {
              visibility: "off"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    return map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  });

}).call(this);
```

AJAX response:

```
moveToLocation(-34, 150);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scripts loaded via jquery(e.g. via `$.getScript`) will be executed in global context, but moveToLocation is not defined in global context.

you must make the function global accessible:

```
window.moveToLocation= ......
```